# At next new agent in the same Jenkins Pipeline, how to get customized environment variable in last ended agent (using AWS Code commit Jenkins project)

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, amazon-eks, aws-codecommit

I deploy Jenkins on EKS, my pipeline is:

```
pipeline {
    stage("build") {
        //start a agent "agent_label"
    }

    //Now, end that agent, for the reason of waiting for user input.

    stage("deploy") {
        //start the agent "agent_label"
    }
 
}
```

At the "build" stage, I get the git commit version, I want to use it in the "deploy" stage. Because the agent terminates, the environment variable in the "build" stage will be unavaliable. So how to solve it?

I have searched for it. It says I should use "Persistent Parameter". But there isn't a "Persistent Parameter" configuration on the Jenkins project type of "AWS Code commit" that I use. I only see that configuration on on the Jenkins project type of "Pipeline".

Another way may be changing the Jenkins BUILD_NUMBER to git commit version. But I do not know how to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the parameter can persistent even if the agent is shut down and restart. For example, if I set a varable in "build" stage, I can still get it at the "deploy" stage.

Also, for changing the Jenkins BUILD_NUMBER environment variable, you can use [Build name setter plugin for Jenkins](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-name-setter/).